# Custom module: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, module, drupal-7

I'm trying my hands on writing my own Drupal module, and I came to the point where I wanted to include Javascript. I tried including a very simple jquery file, but I keep getting Uncaught 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'.
I already updated Drupal's version of jQuery.

For reference, these are the scripts I'm using.

My .info file

```
name = Test
description = A slideshow that implements the PgwSlider Javascript.
core = 7.x
```

My .module file

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_help().
 *
 * Displays help and module information.
 *
 * @param path 
 *   Which path of the site we're using to display help
 * @param arg 
 *   Array that holds the current path as returned from arg() function
 */
function test_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#pgwslider":
      return '<p>' . t("Displays a slideshow") . '</p>';
      break;
  }
}

function test_init() {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'test') .'/styles.css');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'test') .'/test.js');
}
```

My .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    console.log('test')
});
```

Any ideas?

Second, smaller question:

Is this the optimal way of including js files? I know that in themes this is done in the .info file, but for modules, I found no comprehensive answer.

Thanks a bunch guys!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the paths of your .js file is correct, you have to read some [standards of JavaScript code](https://www.drupal.org/node/172169):

All of your JS code must be declared like below:

```
/**
 * @file
*/
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  // Your js code

})(jQuery);
```

Your way to add JS is good enough, but I recommend you to use [hook_library()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7).

Comment: Or use `jQuery` instead of `$` sign. `jQuery(this).hide();` should work fine.

Comment: I'm sure my path is correct, because I can see the test.js file loaded when inspecting the resources.
This is what I have now, but I still get the same error.. I've read the Drupal documentation, but alas.

`/**
 * @file
 */
(function () {
  "use strict";


  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('p').click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  });
  console.log('test');
  });


})(jQuery);`

EDIT: Pastebin for cleaner code http://pastebin.com/Gczd0m3T

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. I copied the code from the drupal documentation, which had no $ sign in the enclosing function's parameters. Thanks!